# Any way to get bar-chart (upside-down) with percent change in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have trade data (import /export of grocery products by worldwide), and I intend to render some plots that indicates worldwide import-export trade flow. To do so, I manipulated my dataframe by using `group_by`, `pivot_table` that will be used as input for plotting function. Seems I didn't get correct manipulation on my data, as a result, I didn't get correct plot that I expected for. Can anyone point me out how to make this work? Thanks

based on this original data, I want to show top 10 countries that get beef export from US. How can I get that?

**minimal example**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list('EEEIEEIIEI'), 
          ['AR', 'AUC', 'CA', 'CN', 'MX', 'MX', 'AR', 'IT', 'UK', 'RU'],
          ['ALBANIA', 'PAKISTN', 'UGANDA', 'FRANCE', 'USA', 'RUSSIA', 'COLOMBIA', 'KAZAK', 'KOREA', 'JAPAN'],
          [20230, 20220, 20120, 20230, 20230, 20220, 20230, 20120, 20130, 20329],
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100000, 10)),
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 10)),
          list(np.random.randint(10, 100, 10)),
          np.random.choice(pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=365, freq='D'), 10, replace=False)]
          ).T

df.columns =['ID', 'cty', 'cty_ptn', 'prod_code', 'value','Quantity1', 'Quantity2', 'date']

my_dict={'20230':'Gas',
        '20220':'Water',
        '20210': 'Refined',
        '20120':'Oil',
        '20239':'Other'}

df['prod_label']=df['prod_code'].astype(str).map(my_dict)
```

**my attempt**:

I tried the following manipulation for creating bar plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot.plt
%matplotlib inline

    mydf= mydf[(mydf['prod_label']=='Gas') & (mydf['ID']=='E')]
```

**updated attempt**:

```
mydf=mydf.groupby('cty_ptn')['value','Quantity1'].sum().reset_index()
mydf=mydf.nlargest(20, 'Quantity1')

## EDA 
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.scatter(mydf['Quantity1'].values, mydf['value'].values)
```

**my current output**

I got this dummy plot that is far from what I expected:

[image]

but I didn't get the correct plot here (it is empty, I don't know why). The reason is most likely I got wrong manipulated data which not match for the input for `matplotlib` plot function. Any quick correction?

**desired plot**:

I am trying to achieve the following plot (inspired by trade data report):

[image]

how can I get above plot? what sort of manipulation is needed before hitting plot function? Thanks

Comment: _but I didn't get correct plot here._ What did you get instead?

Comment: _I got value error._ That has to be included in your post, then. See: [ask], [mcve].

Comment: _but I didn't get the correct plot here (it is empty, I don't know why)._ Did you check that whatever is being fed to the plotting functions isn't empty?

Comment: @AMC yeah, I checked value, it is `pd.Series` object and it is not empty. I shared a minimal dataset using this gist [this gist](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/cb2341b98110db8a82651c72e0ad57d5). Any thoughts?

Comment: I would like to run the MCVE, are `df` and `mydf` different names for the same variable?

Comment: I've installed matplotlib, yet I'm getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot.plt'; 'matplotlib.pyplot' is not a package".

Comment: _df should be type._ What do you mean? _You can use seaborn instead. Do you think how to get that desired plot? Thanks_ Did you read my second comment? I'm literally in the middle of trying to run your program so that I can attempt to debug it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206399/discussion-between-beyond-inifinity-and-amc).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/julaiti/cb2341b98110db8a82651c72e0ad57d5/raw/5ab24d37619adb720118d8d7742fa8c52d799492/minimal_dataset')
df.groupby(['partner'])['qty1'].sum().nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: that's what I did but I want to plot that percentage change should be expressed (export percentage dropped or increased). Any way to get the desired plot that I attached above? Thanks

Comment: percent change between what and what?

Comment: The problem is not the plotting, the problem is to define *what* you want to plot. To calculate a percentage change, you need e.g. a *before* and an *after*. How do you define these?

Comment: actually I want to see US beef/swine export and import production percentage change, I just updated [minimal dataset](https://gist.github.com/julaiti/cb2341b98110db8a82651c72e0ad57d5/edit). the point is while US beef export increased or dropped how swine export change and vise versa for the opposite.I think now we can define good plotting data. Any updated solution?